# Nucleo-L432KC USART can only send data but not receive from putty

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, embedded, arm, cortex-m4

trying to use virtual com port of the mentioned Nucleo board [DATASHEET](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/dm00151940-stm32l41xxx42xxx43xxx44xxx45xxx46xxx-advanced-armbased-32bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf) I can send chars nicely to the putty output but now wants to be able to send commands too from putty

the peripheral is configuered as shown the mcu clock is left as MSI 4mhz (default)
in GDB the interrupt is only triggered once in startup despite no data being sent yet from putty.
no triggering occurs when trying to send any data from putty after

RDR seems to always have a 0 value
ISR however seems to set frame error and RXNE randomly

EDIT:
It appears that I might have used the wrong pin on the board there's 2 pins for USART2-RX (PA15 and PA3) I searched the reference manual and the datasheet of the board for the St-link connection with no luck any idea where I can find those ?

```
.syntax unified

.include "stm32l432kc.inc"
.global main

.section .data
UART_string:
    .space  100     
stringIndex:
    .byte   0x00

.section .text
main:
    bl      UART_init
    @send one string just to verify peripheral is working 
    ldr     r0, =printString
    bl      UART_send

    nop
    b       .


UART_init:
    push    {lr}
    @first Enable clock for the GPIO port used for the uart
    ldr     r1, =RCC_AHB2ENR
    ldr     r0, [r1]
    orr     r0, #(1 << 0)
    str     r0, [r1]

    @configure the pins for usart peripheral 
    @set the PA2, PA3 to alternate function mode 7 for the USART2 (writing 10 into each pin)
    ldr     r1, =GPIOA_MODER
    ldr     r0, [r1]
    orr     r0, #(5 << 5)       @setting the highest bit of each pin together
    str     r0, [r1]
    ldr     r2, =(5 << 4)       @clearing the lowest bit of each pin together  
    mvn     r2, r2
    and     r0, r2
    str     r0, [r1]

    @next put value 7 in the alternate function reg 
    ldr     r1, =GPIOA_AFRL
    ldr     r0, [r1]
    orr     r0, #(7 << 8)
    orr     r0, #(7 << 12)
    str     r0, [r1]

    @seoncdly configure the USART2 peripheral
    @enable the clock for USART2 peripheral
    ldr     r1, =RCC_APB1ENR1
    ldr     r0, [r1]
    orr     r0, #(1 << 17)
    str     r0, [r1]

    @enable HSI16
    ldr     r1, =RCC_CR
    mov     r0, #(1 << 8)
    str     r0, [r1]
    @wait for HSIRDY bit
    wait0:
        mov     r0, #(1 << 10)
        ldr     r2, [r1]
        ands    r0, r2
        beq     wait0

    @choose HSI16 for usart2
    ldr     r1, =RCC_CCIPR
    ldr     r0, [r1]
    orr     r0, #(1 << 3)
    str     r0, [r1]

    @load the baud rate of 9600 to BRR
    ldr     r1, =USART2_BRR
    ldr     r0, =1667
    str     r0, [r1]

    @enable the transmission, receive block and usart peripheral 
    ldr     r1, =USART2_CR1
    ldr     r0, =(3 << 2)
    str     r0, [r1]
    orr     r0, #(1 << 0)
    str     r0, [r1]

    @reset the flags in ISR
    ldr     r1, =USART2_ICR
    ldr     r0, =0
    mvn     r0, r0
    str     r0, [r1]

    @set the RXNE (receive interrupt enable bit 5 in CR1)
    ldr     r1, =USART2_CR1
    ldr     r0, [r1]
    orr     r0, #(1 << 5)
    str     r0, [r1]

    @enable the interrupt from the NVIC_ISER1
    ldr     r1, =NVIC_ISER1
    mov     r0, #(1 << 6)       
    str     r0, [r1]

    pop     {lr}
    bx      lr


UART_send:
    cpsid   i
    push    {lr}
    mov     r3, r0
    ldr     r1, =USART2_TDR
    ldr     r2, =USART2_ISR
1:
    ldrb    r0, [r3]
    strb    r0, [r1]
    add     r3, #1
    wait:
        ldr     r4, [r2]
        ands    r4, #(1 << 7)
        beq     wait
    tst     r0, r0
    beq     return
    b       1b
return:
    cpsie   i
    pop     {lr}
    bx      lr

.global USART2_IRQHandler
.type USART2_IRQHandler, %function
USART2_IRQHandler:
    push    {lr}
    ldr     r1, =USART2_RDR
    ldr     r2, =UART_string
    ldr     r4, =stringIndex
    add     r2, r4
    ldr     r3, =USART2_ISR
    
    eor     r0, r0
    ldrb    r0, [r1]
    strb    r0, [r2]
    tst     r0, r0
    beq     1f
    b       2f
1:  
    @reset the index register for one complete string
    ldr     r1, =stringIndex
    mov     r0, #0
    str     r0, [r1]
    @print the received string
    ldr     r0, =UART_string
    bl      UART_send

2:
    @clear the pending bit
    ldr     r1, =NVIC_ICPR1
    mov     r0, #(1 << 6)
    str     r0, [r1]
    @increment index
    ldr     r1, =stringIndex
    ldr     r0, [r1]
    add     r0, #1
    str     r0, [r1]
    pop     {lr}
    bx      lr


.type printString, %object
printString:
    .string "Hello world!\r\n"
```

Comment: Do you clear all interrupt flags? NVIC pending?

Comment: @llya yes, I clear the pending bit in the end of the USART handler

Comment: I don't see you disable overrun. Try to do that and see if anything changes. I'm not good at assembly (next to zero), but I kinda intuitively understand what you do since I wrote my own driver in C recently heh.

Comment: @llya still nothing the RDR value is always zero and the USART2 interrupt only triggered after the UART_send function

Comment: Set breakpoints in the middle of the code after you setup the USART and see USART register contents after you send something. Check that all interrupt enables are enabled and stuff. Well, everything. Or simply get to infinite loop and press pause/play.

Comment: the interrupt flag is set and the handler triggers early after the UART_send function prints a '\000' and never triggers again
I see however some people leaving the Rx pin as (input float I think this is equal to analog mode ?) while others seem to set the pin as alternate function as I did, tried making the RX bin as analog with no luck though

Comment: Pin mode is MCU-specific. Some require alternate function, some input. Your job is to figure out why it triggers early and stops triggering at all. You may want to put a few breakpoints to check flags in both USART and NVIC at different moments in time. Breakpoints with communication are an uncomfortable problem. As I've mentioned, I don't understand much in assembly, therefore I can't help you any further.

Comment: @llya  the problem is not with the code itself I think the MCU pin-mode is ok but it appears I have might used the wrong pin for the virtual com port there's 2 pins for USART2-RX can't find which one belongs to the virtual com port from the datasheet and reference manual any Idea on where I can find the stlink connection 
-thanks for your effort

Comment: Have a look at the schematic of the board, might be the slowest way to find the information, but usually the schematic doesn't lie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The board user manual section 6.9 says PA15 is the default receive pin.